# mysql connector/J 8 changes - version 8.0.12

Tags: java, mysql, sql, mysql-connector

While performing getString operation in MYSQL connector/J 8 version , date is being returned as string instead of NULL even after using **zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL**

While using connector version 5.x or previous, this was not the case.
Setting this property in connection string didn't help either  - **noDatetimeStringSync=false/true**

Suppose DB is having TABLE1 and has a DATE_TIME COLUMN of type date

```
 stmt=con.prepareStatement("select DATE_TIME FROM TABLE1");
 ResultSet rs1 = stmt.executeQuery();

   while (rs1.next()) {
        //mapcheck is a hash map of type <String , object>
    mapCheck.put("_Key:", rs1.getString("DATE_TIME"));

    }
```

This would return 0000-00-00 while using connector version 8. Any idea how to make it return null as it was in case of mysql connector version 5.x

Comment: [1] Update your post with the exact version of the Connector/J 8 driver (8.0.12?), and the version of Java that you are using. [2] How are you specifying **zeroDateTimeBehavior=CONVERT_TO_NULL**? Within the connection string? [3] Are you running your code within an IDE? If so, which one (Eclipse, Intellij IDEA, NetBeans, etc)? [4] Can you delete that **sql-server** tag since it doesn't seem to be relevant for your question.

Comment: yes @skomisa , i am using that within the connection string. And  believe it is reproducible with all of the IDE. The mysql version is 5.7 and java version that i am using is jdk1.8.0_171